# List all commits before a given commit with Github GraphQL API v4

Tags: github, github-api, github-api-v4

I'm trying to list all commit on a branch between the latest commit and a given commit.

It seems that the history(before) is not working as intended. The query below gives me the first 100 commit on that branch without respecting the before cursor I specified. history(after) seems to be working just fine. Am I misunderstanding something here?

```graphql
{
  repository(owner: "prestodb", name: "presto") {
        ref(qualifiedName: "release-0.235") {
            target {
                ... on Commit {
                    history(before: "f9f9d83c84dbb35fc49e5b4c70326024d8ff3d1e 0") {
                        pageInfo {
                            hasNextPage
                            endCursor
                        }
                        edges {
                            node {
                                oid
                                message
                                # author {
                                #     name
                                # }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```